# How am getting this output ? Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, function, loops, ecmascript-6

Please find my snippet here,

```js
for (var i=0;i<11;i++) {
  setTimeout( () => console.log(i), 10);
}
```

How it print `11` for 11 times? since `i` was set < 11?

if i console it without function it print 1-10 .

```
for (var i=0;i<11;i++) {
  setTimeout( console.log(i), 10);
}
```

this gives me 1-10. i am wonder how its getting changed if i include function without condition?

Comment: There's only one `i`, and when the timers fire its value is 11.

Comment: to expand on what @Pointy said, `setTimeout` is an asynchronous function, so by the time the first log happens, the for loop has already finished running (it performs `i++` until `i<11` is false, and the first time that happens is when `i === 11`)

Comment: Because variables are references​

Comment: @PatrickBarr which alos explains why it starts printing with 1. If there were no setTimeout() then it would print 0..10, not 1..11.

Comment: @Darkrum: That's not true in this case because `i` is a number. What's happening is that functions create closures. `i` is enclosed.

Comment: @manassehkatz: It doesn't start printing with 1. It starts printing with 11. It prints 11,11,11 ... ten times

Comment: @slebetman I saw a mention in the question of 1-10. Depending on timing it could be almost anything - except the "normal" 0..10.

Comment: Also no one has mentioned the second one will print the numbers without waiting, setTimeout will receive the result of calling console.log

Comment: @manassehkatz: This specific example does not depend on timing and it is not anything. It is 11, 11, 11 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root case for:

```
for (var i=0;i<11;i++) {
  setTimeout( console.log(i), 10);
}
```

that `console.log` will be triggered directly (without any delay), so it should be:

```
for (var i=0;i<11;i++) {
  setTimeout(function () { console.log(i); }, 10);
}
```

that will give directly the same result as for ES6

Right way will be by using closures:

```js
for (var i=0;i<11;i++) {
    ((i) => { 
        setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 10);
    })(i);
}
```

The reason for that that we have a single-threaded model in JavaScript. So, all `setTimeout` will be executed **after** `for`-cycle.

In addition it can be used `let`:

```
for (let i=1; i<=11; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 10);
}
```

Comment: Given the question asks explicitly about ES6, no this is not the solution.

Comment: Hm... `setTimeout( console.log(i), 10);` - console.log will be executed outside the setTimeout. That's the case...

Comment: I've updated the answer

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. I meant you should not use IIFEs to introduce scopes in ES6.

Comment: @Bergi, what would you suggest in that case? It's rather common solution: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch5.md

Comment: See the linked duplicate.

Comment: *"by using closures"* That is not the reason that solution works. The reason it works is that you are *creating a new scope* by *calling* a function. Whether that function is a closure or not is irrelevant. The function you are passing to `setTimeout` is also a closure but doesn't produce the desired result without the IIFE. So saying "use a closure to solve this" is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i=0;i<11;i++) {
  setTimeout( () => console.log(i), 10);
}
```

1. Do reference for i
2. Push on stack timeout
3. i++
4. Push on stack timeout
5. i++

   ... when js has free main "thread" after execution of for loop

   10 ms after pushing timeout AND while main "thread" is free - push the first timeout to main "thread", referenced variable has value 11 because for loop is done. Do this for every timeout.

The expected output can be archived by:

```
for (var i=0;i<11;i++) {
  const num = i;
  setTimeout(() => console.log(num), 10);
}
```

Const `num` stores the value of `i` to the time of execution. After that it is garbagecollected.

Comment: Have you tried to execute it?) Check the last number.

Comment: Perfectly fine. It is returning stack. You can do `null &&` before timeout

Comment: you are calling `console.log` immediately on every iteration of the loop and passing the return value of that to `setTimeout` which would be undefined. Not delaying the call to console.log. Try increasing the setTimeout delay to something larger like `10000` and you will see that it isn't delaying anything.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn right! sorry for mistake. Fixed

Comment: @DanielMizerski, check execution: http://i64.tinypic.com/forrp.png

Comment: @FieryCat And what is the issue? The 33 and 44 that is logged is not from the console.log, it would likely be the internal id from the last setTimeout call (return value from setTimeout). When running code in the console, it will automatically log the return value from the last called function. Aside from that, it looks perfectly fine.